# app.PressEnter() on Xamarin UI.test

Tags: ios, testing, automated-tests, xamarin.uitest

I'm trying to do app.PressEnter(); when the keyboard appears on my iPad. The type of keyboard that appears has the option to "search" instead of "intro". On a keyboard with the "intro" option it works.

Any idea for it to work?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Code, screenshots? Not clear what are you asking for.

Comment: Thanks I have solved it. I put a try - catch to control that the error does not end the test

Comment: It's better to describe your issue and answer to your question by yourself. It could be useful for somebody else in future ;)